# BLOCK element inside a Table

Tags: html, css

With this combination of CSS and HTML, why is `<header>HEADER</header>` rendered above `<nav>NAVIGATION</nav>`?

```css
#wrapper { display: table; }
header   { display: table-header-group; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>NAVIGATION</nav>
  <header>HEADER</header>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean, "malformatted"?

Comment: I don't understand your question nor what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please don't make people click through to a fiddle site to see the code you're asking about.

Comment: @MarcB  Edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<nav>` element has `display:block` and it's the immediate child of an element with `display:table`, so the layout engine generates "anonymous wrapper boxes" around it to force it to conform to the table formatting model.  Similarly, the bare text node inside the `<header>` element, which has `display:table-header-group`, is wrapped up.  The "box tree" that results is the same as if you had written this HTML with no CSS:

```html
<table>
<tbody><tr><td><div>NAVIGATION</div></td></tr></tbody>
<thead><tr><td><div>HEADER</div></td></tr></thead>
</table>
```

And a `<table>` is specified to show the contents of its `<thead>` first, then its `<tbody>`, so you get HEADER and then NAVIGATION.

See the discussion of "[layout-internal display types](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#layout-specific-display)" in the [CSS3 Display](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/) specification. EXAMPLE 1 in particular describes something very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

If by "malformatted" you mean not aligned properly, no - because you are setting the display of the wrapper to table. This is not an actual table HTML element.